# Asp.Net Core 5.0 Using jQuery in Partial View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, partial-views

I am using a partial view with Ajax to display User Data on the Main View. The script runs from the main view.

Now I want to add a 'delete' button to the results in the partial, but I am having problem in writing a script with an ajax call in the partial view.

How can I solve this problem by treating the partial form data with jQuery and Ajax?

This is my partial view:

```
@foreach (var i in Model.Users)
{

        <div>
            <form id="deletForm">
                <input name="Id" id="Id" value="@i.Id" hidden />
                <input name="UserId" id="userId" value="@i.ApplicationUserId" hidden />
                <button type="submit" class="close-icon" id="deleteBtn"></button>
            </form>
            <div class="class" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@i.ApplicationUser.FullName">@i.ApplicationUser.Name.ToUpper()</div>
        </div>
    
}



<script>
    $("#deleteBtn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $("#deletForm").serialize();
        alert(formdata);
        alert('I got here');

    });
</script>
```

Comment: HI, can you elaborate more on your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to add a 'delete' button to the results in the partial, but I am having problem in writing a script with an ajax call in the partial view.

Please note that you put the `<form id="deletForm">` within `@foreach` looping in your partial view, which would cause many html elements with same `id` attribute.

To achieve your requirement, you can try to modify the code like below.

*In partial view*

```
@foreach (var i in Model.Users)
{

    <div>
        <form class="deletForm">
            <input name="Id" value="@i.Id" hidden />
            <input name="UserId" value="@i.ApplicationUserId" hidden />
            <button type="submit" class="close-icon deleteBtn"></button>
        </form>
        <div class="class" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@i.ApplicationUser.FullName">@i.ApplicationUser.Name.ToUpper()</div>

}
```

*In main view*

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".deleteBtn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formdata = $(this).parent(".deletForm").serialize();
            alert(formdata);
            alert('I got here');

            //code logic here of making ajax request(s)
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem that I encounter is that the script is not run on this section. I have modified the partial view and added the screen in the main View, but the script cannot reach the partial section.

Comment: In the main View I am using Kendo Wizard component. I have added  `$(document).on('focusin', '.deleteBtn', function () { }` ,now the script implements, but the problem is that if I add 3 entries if I click on the first added one the script runs 3 times, on the second added one on 2 times, and on the third added one it runs once. So it runs In a loop for all added elements. How can I prevent this behaviour and make it run only once for each form? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What I noticed the loop does not depend on the number of the entries added, but it depends how much I have clicked on the button.

Comment: Can you share the detailed code of your main view?